# Multi-stage Docker build doesn't copy files created from the previous stage

Tags: python, node.js, docker, npm

I have a Django app whose Docker build is two stages:

- 1st stage uses a Node image to compile static assets using Gulp. This stage creates the `node_modules` directory and a folder named `build`.
- 2nd stage is supposed to copy files from the previous stage and install the python dependencies.

My problem is that the new folders created by the 1st stage aren't being carried over.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
# STAGE 1: Compile static assets
# ----------------------------
FROM node:17-slim as client-builder

ARG APP_HOME=/code

WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

COPY . ${APP_HOME}
# npm's post-install script will use GulpJs to compile the static 
# assets into a folder named "build"
RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force


# STAGE 2: Add python dependencies
# ----------------------------
FROM python:3.10-slim as python-build-stage

ARG APP_HOME=/code
ARG USERNAME=docker

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV POETRY_NO_INTERACTION 1
ENV POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE false
ENV POETRY_CACHE_DIR "/var/cache/pypoetry"
ENV POETRY_HOME "/usr/local"

WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

# Create the user
RUN addgroup --system ${USERNAME} \
    && adduser --system --ingroup ${USERNAME} ${USERNAME}

# Install apt packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
  # dependencies for building Python packages
  build-essential \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  libpq-dev \
  # dev utils
  git zsh

# Copy project files
COPY --from=client-builder --chown=${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} ${APP_HOME} ${APP_HOME}

# Install python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install poetry
RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi

# Set default shell
RUN chsh -s $(which zsh)

# Set user
USER ${USERNAME}
```

### Things I tried

- The first stage runs correctly. Gulp.js is able to run, so `node_modules` must have been created correctly. I tried to debug the first stage and saw all files being created correctly.
- Also tried running as root
- I also tried to "log" the contents of the workspace with `RUN ls . >> /tmp/ls.txt` and the contents of the file list surprised me:

I can see the folders being listed there:

[image]

But when I `ls` the actual workspace, I don't see anything:

[image]

What is happening?

### Docker-compose

I forgot to mention, I'm using docker-compose to build and start these images:

```
version: '3.10'

services:
  db.postgres:
    image: "postgres"
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  web:
    build: .
    command: >
      zsh -c "python3 /code/manage.py migrate &&
              python3 /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db.postgres
    restart: on-failure:5

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Comment: How exactly are you starting this image?

Comment: I'm using docker-compose. I'll add it to the post

Comment: And there it is...you have a `volumes` configuration that is mounting your local directory over `/code`, masking anything that you placed there during the build phase.

Comment: /*pikuchu face/* Could it be? (I'm testing right now). I was under the impression volume worked both ways (i.e. the Docker content would reflect on the host).  Is there a way for me to have the cake and eat it too (i.e. have a 2-stage docker build and a volumes connection)?

Comment: The solution is place the data generated during the build process somewhere other than `/code`. I don't know enough about what you're doing, but possibly some combination of code changes and environment variables will allow this to work.

Comment: @larsks you've hit the nail on the head! I added a second volume (so now I have `.:/code` and `/code/build/` so that there will be a `build` directory at the container regardless of what exists in the host.

Please add your answer below so I can mark it as right and give you points!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that during the build process you're installing
things into the `/code` directory:

```
ARG APP_HOME=/code
...
COPY --from=client-builder --chown=${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} \
  ${APP_HOME} ${APP_HOME}
```

But in your `docker-compose.yaml`, you're masking the `/code`
directory by mounting your local directory on top of it:

```
  web:
    ...
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

That means anything placed there during the build process will be
hidden.

One solution is to mount your local directory somewhere other than
`/code` (and then update your code/config/whatever to be aware of the
new mountpoint).